# Password toggle for multiple TextInputLayouts

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, textinputlayout

I have two TextInputLayouts where the first one gets the password input and the second one gets the confirmed password input. I'm completely okay with the single-input layout toggle change. However, I wanted to also toggle the other password input layout automatically. Couldn't find such implementation on the documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: what exactly do you want ? can u expalin it in more details please?

Comment: I have two TextInputLayout in a single layout. Enter Password + Confirm Password. Both have a password toggle icon at the end of TextInputLayout. Once the user clicked on this icon on one of these text input layout views, I want both views to toggle (show the password for both / hide password for both automatically). I don't want user to toggle both input views manually @D_K

Comment: can u show me you java code ?? if u implemented ??